# exe from jar can't access MySQL from localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jar, launch4j

I have an GUI application that connect to MySQL through xampp. Running with netbeans is fine, but when I wrap it to exe using Launch4j from the jar, it can't connect to the database (it reaches the exception even though the interface still working)

I've choose custom classpath and it contains the mysql library.

[image]

And this is what throws the exception:

```
try
        {
          // create our mysql database connection
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vietcombank.db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8","admin", "123456789");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

The output of the exception is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. But if I run the jar itself by cmd with direct location as `java -jar "D:\Network Programming\ServerATM\dist\ServerATM.jar"` it run just fine. Is it because Launch4j didn't include the libraries?

Thank you.

Comment: The code cannot recognise com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. you need to add the jars in the required classpath

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `e.getMessage()`.  Did you copy the `lib` directory along with the exe (not familiar with Launch4j)

Comment: @KalaiarasanManimaran When I choose the main class like the image above, it auto detects those 2 libraries. And I can't manually point the classpath to a particular jar library.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Copying `lib` folder along with the exe works for me! But can't it just wrap the libraries into the exe file?

Answer (score 0):

instead of this :

`private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/your-database-name";`

Try to use this :

`private String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/your-database-name";`

Answer (score 0):

Move the executable file you created to the dist folder, it worked for me